# taking control over a phone with broken touchscreen

Tags: broken-screen, sony-xperia-z

I have an old sony xperia z with a broken touchscreen, the phone holds a lot of important data but with the broken touchscreen I cant get the data.

I've tried a lot of things but I do not have  usb debugging enabled and it is not rooted.

Comment: When you say broken touchscreen, is it only the touch input feature that is broken, or the actual display that doesn't show anything?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone support OTG
Then connect your phone with mouse,copy your all data..

Hope it will solve your problem...

Comment: It won't solve it if the screen doesn't show anything. OP didn't clarify whether that's the case.